# How to get Answer object with variables in Rightnow SOAP API

Tags: rightnow-crm

I'm simply trying to get all Answer by following ROQL

```
SELECT A FROM Answer A
```

This returns answers but when I see Solution's value, it contains `$variableName`. I have the variable configured and see it properly in preview, but how can I get complete Solution value after `$variableName` gets translated to actual content through the Rightnow SOAP API?

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, the API presents the raw solution string and not the calculated string with variables replaced.  This happens for a number of reasons; the UI is aware of interface / language, calculations or other variable changes at run time, and more.  Therefore, the SOAP API isn't aware of the context of the variable to replace it at query time through ROQL.  Depending on how your variable is constructed, you would probably need to programmatically replace the variables based on logic behind that variable in your answer.

As a side note, selecting all answers through an object query (instead of a tabular query for just the fields that you want) can be expensive (technically).  What's the business case behind selecting all answers in this way?

Comment: Getting all answers is an example, but I do need to get a list of answers, perhaps like 20 per page. Then, I'll have to show a part of Solution as well as Subject. Since getting variables for each answer one by one is a bit expensive in a single request, I'm almost thinking to show Summary instead, which doesn't contain any variables. Then I create a detail answer page where all answer's Solution with variables' value can be viewed.

Comment: Are you doing this outside of customer portal?  Seems like you can use the default answer list and answer details pages for this in CP.  Including CP in an iFrame into a parent site might be an option if you are trying to load it directly.  Also checkout syndicated answer widget(s).

Comment: we are actually replacing that CP iframe. so we can have a bit more flexibility entirely

Comment: The problem with that approach is that the Web Services APIs don't provide parity for the features that Customer Portal provides.  So, you will be able to mockup alot of the basic functionality using API calls, but diving into the more advanced features might leave you wanting the iFrame approach again.  What is the current problem with the iFrame approach that you are trying to get around?

Answer (score 1):

Use Knowledge API instead - variables will be replaced with actual values.

Comment: Trying to get that API call now

Comment: Yes, it seems working! but I have some limitations with this API I need to find workaround. Looks like `SearchContent()` function doesn't allow me to search all contents by just product filter. I am forced to supply `SearchTerms` otherwise it throws exception "Data element in the Message is NULL". do you know anything about that?

Comment: SearchTerms is a required parameter and cannot be omitted.  Though, you may be able to supply a wildcard to circumvent it (though you probably shouldn't do that).  You might also want to check about the billing implications before moving to the KF API.  If I recall correctly, it falls under a different bucket than your Connect API bucket.  Your Oracle rep should be able to answer that question for you.  Using the KF API to build your own KB is outside of the intended use case, so you probably want to consider this architecture carefully.